# Set AllowTransparency individually to an WebBrowser

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

On my WPF Application, i have an WebBrowser and rounded Window Edegs. I want to set the Background to tranparent, what only Works if AllowsTransparency is set to True. On the WebBrowser you need it to have AllowsTransparency set to False.
But how can i set the Background of the Window to Transparent, and still be able to see the WebBrowser?

MainWindow.xaml:

```xml
<Window x:Class="ok.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Width="564.68" Height="300" 
    WindowStyle="None"
    Background="Transparent"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Border Background="#FF141414" CornerRadius="10,10,10,10" Padding="8" BorderThickness=".65">
        <Border.BorderBrush>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FF005DFF" Offset="0.5" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FF00FFF0" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.BorderBrush>
        <Grid Background="#FF0F0F0F" Loaded="Grid_Loaded" Margin="-5,-5,-5,-5">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="96*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="29*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="88*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="359*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="101*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="15" Height="15" Background="#FFEE0A0A" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                <Button.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="Border">
                        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="1003"/>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Resources>
            </Button>
            <Button Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="15" Height="15" Background="#FFE2C300" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                <Button.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="1003"/>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Resources>
            </Button>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="1" Margin="-29,19,-24,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="600" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Background="#FF555555" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1">
                <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1"/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
            </StackPanel>
            <Label Content="Cerium" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="41,-3,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="59" Foreground="White" Height="29" FontFamily="Yu Gothic" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
            <TabControl x:Name="TabCtrl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="228" Margin="4,22,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="543" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Background="#FF0F0F0F" BorderBrush="#FF282828" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Row="1">
            </TabControl>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the IE browser supports transparency as stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/changov/webbrowser-control-on-transparent-wpf-window)
A similar question was also asked [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/61a901d3-3273-4d8e-8e08-9441dc11010f/wpf-webbrowser-in-a-transparent-window?forum=wpf). Where many has stated that it is not supported.

You can try and use another browser engine like Chromium. This can be implemented through CefSharp the GitHub is [here](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp).

You can download it via NuGet using this command

```
Install-Package CefSharp.Wpf -Version 83.3.120-pre
```